# Rails pluck error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

error undefined method `pluck' for # User:0x00000007234e28

I want to get the details of the last two registered users.

```
def index
    if User.exists?
        user1 = User.first.pluck(:id)
        user2 = User.second.pluck(:id)
    end
end
```

Comment: User.first is selecting the first element, you can just use 'User.first.id', to get the id, `pluck` works on a ActiveRecord array only.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you can do the following

```
def index
  last_two_users = User.order(created_at: :asc).limit(2).pluck(:id)
end
```

You can sort on the `created_at` column if you have one, or on the `id` column. If you use the `id` column change `asc` to `desc`.

A different way is to use map:

```
last_two_users = User.last(2).map(&:id)
```

The `last_two_users` will have the last 2 users added to your table.